# Запуск WhatsApp из Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin, viber, whatsapp

Коллеги, доброго времени суток.

Не могу найти конкретной информации в интернете, каким образом можно запустить из моего приложения, другое приложение? Например тот же самый **WhatsApp** или **Viber**?

Что необходимо написать в XAML или файле *.cs?

Банальный код в XAML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:Spravochnik"
         x:Class="Spravochnik.MainPage">
<StackLayout>
    <Button x:Name="openMessage" Text="open WhatsApp" Clicked="openMessage_Clicked"/>
</StackLayout>

</ContentPage>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Тебя интересует работа с нативным API. В Xamarin это делается через [DependencyService](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/dependency-service/introduction). После создания интерфейса, описывающего открытие WhatsApp, его реализация на Android скатывается в банальный вызов Intent. Соответственно, смотришь [код](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38422300/how-to-open-whatsapp-using-an-intent-in-your-android-app) на Java и реализуешь, активно пользуясь Namespace Resolve в Visual Studio. В современных студиях там еще лампочка в контектстном меню...

[image: namespace-resolve]

У меня есть [репозиторий](https://github.com/tripolskypetr/NearestMetro) на GitHub, где я по тому же принципу реализую получение последнего местоположения. Возможно, исходный код этого решения пригодиться.

Comment: Спасибо) Буду изучать)